# Rinow's student Dombrowski article about curvature-related measures

Tags: differential-geometry

$\mathbf{Preamble}$: I read [this article](https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/abs/10.1002/mana.19680380302) from Peter Dombrowski, a student of famous mathematician Rinow. On page 167, he explicates the equation for the geodesic curve of submerged surface $\mathbb{S}$ of dimension $m$ into a Euclidean manifold $\mathbb{R}^n$ defined by $m$ equalities $\{\varphi_l = 0\}_{l \in \mathbb{N}^+_{\leq m}}$. We can, for example, recognize the second-kind Christoffel symbol $\Gamma_{ij}^k$ as expression $\sum\limits_{\lambda \mu} \left( \Phi_{\lambda \mu} \, \frac{\partial^2 \varphi_\lambda}{\partial u_i \partial u_j} \frac{\partial \varphi_\mu}{\partial u_k} \right)$ evaluated at curve point $c(t)$. I fail to understand the ellipsoid example $\lambda_1 x_1^2 + \lambda_2 x_2^2 + \lambda_3 x_3^2 - 1 = 0$ in ellipsoidal coordinates.

$\mathbf{Question}$: The calculation in Euclidean coordinates ($x$, $y$ and $z$) goes well since it corresponds to an application of the aforementioned formula. In elliptical coordinates, the equation above corresponds to a plane equation $u_1 - 1 = 0$, whose geodesic curves are straight lines. HOWEVER, the geodesic curves over an ellipsoid are not the map $x(u(t))$ of straight lines.

$x(u) = u_1 \,\begin{pmatrix} \frac{1}{\lambda_1} \, \cos{(u_2)} \, \cos{(u_3)} \\ \frac{1}{\lambda_2} \,  \cos{(u_2)} \, \sin{(u_3)} \\ \frac{1}{\lambda_3} \, \sin{(u_2)} \end{pmatrix}$

Do I misunderstand some concept in differential geometry?

Comment: The plane parametrizing the ellipsoid does not come endowed with the euclidean metric: it comes with the pullback metric for which geodesics are not the usual straight lines

Comment: Would you mind providing the pullback metric, in this case, the pullback $F^* T \mathbb{S}$, for paramtrization map $F$ equal to $(x, u(x))$ and inverse map $u(x)$ equal to $x^{-1}(u)$?

Comment: It's just pure computations using the differential of the parametrization you gave. I don't have time to do so but you now have all the ingredients and the reciep, so.. Let's cook!

Comment: Publishable material. Do you have any references in mind? Moreover, in which institution do you pursue Ph.D., my fellow?

Comment: Look what I found: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Induced_metric

Comment: I don't think the institution where I did my PhD is really relevant in this comment section, and I like answering anonymously on this website; regarding your link: yes, the pullback metric is the one induced by the ambient euclidean metric!